# В чём разница между printStackTrace () и System.out.println(exception.getMessage())?

Tags: java, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Предположим, я обрабатываю исключение и в блоке `catch` просто вывожу сообщение об ошибке.

Я могу это сделать так:

```java
try{

//Какой-то код

} catch(IOException exception){
   exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Но могу сделать и так:

```
try{

//Какой-то код

} catch(IOException exception){
   System.err.println(exception.getMessage());
}
```

В чём разница этих двух способов? И какой лучше использовать?

Comment: Я могу ошибаться,  но System выведет сообщение  в системную  консоль, а exception выдет  в системный логгер (который  может быть  системной консолью)

Comment: сообщение об ошибке и "стектрейс" разные вещи

Comment: Учтите, что `getMessage()` имеет право и `null` вернуть. Вывод `null` в качестве диагностики - это не самый лучший вариант для отладки.

Comment: @BccHnw То есть если нужно просто вывести сообщение об ошибке, то метод `printStackTrace()` лучше?

Comment: `printStackTrace` выводит сразу три вещи: название класса исключения, сообщение (`message`, если оно есть, т.е. не равно `null`) и stack trace. Это более громоздко, но именно для диагностики лучше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собрал ответ из всех комментариев под вопросом: по кусочку информации из того, из этого и наконец понял, в чём разница.

Возьмём вот такой код:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         File file = new File("C:" + File.separator + "someFile.txt");
         try(PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file)){
             
             writer.println("something....");

         } catch (IOException e){
              //Здесь будем выводить сообщение об ошибке
         }
    }
}
```

1. `printStackTrace()`. В блоке `catch` пропишем:

```
} catch (IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

В случае, если исключение произойдёт, то на экран будет выведен стектрейс + сообщение об ошибке:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/someFile.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:184)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:309)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

**И сообщение об ошибке, и стектрейс**. Два в одном.

2. `System.err.println(e.getMessage())`. Если прописать в блоке `catch` это:

```
} catch (IOException e){
   System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

То на экран будет выведено **только** сообщение об ошибке, без стектрейса (то есть без списка методов, кто кого вызвал):

```
C:/someFile.txt (No such file or directory)
```

### **Вывод**

Исключения нужно конечно **нормально обрабатывать**, но если всё-таки по какой-то причине вы хотите вывести информацию об исключении в консоль, то пишите `e.printStackTrace()`, ведь это выводит более полную информацию, чем `System.err.println(e.getMessage())`.

**Спасибо всем, кто писал в комментариях или отвечал!**

Answer (score 1):

Имхо - и то и другое неправильно. Ошибки надо логировать, а не выкидывать в консоль.

Так же плохо `System.out`, так как для вывода ошибок есть `System.err`.

[printStackTrace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace()) как раз и выводит стек ошибки в стандартный системный поток для ошибок. Т.е. `System.err`